# Julia broadcasting twice as slow as Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, julia, overhead, broadcasting

I am trying to familiarize myself with Julia in order to migrate from Matlab, so far so good until I started using broadcasting to port a specific function which performs more or less twice as slow as Matlab.

```
function features(X::Vector{Float64},M::Int,hyper::Float64,mid::Float64)
    X = X.-mid
    H = 4.0.*hyper.+maximum(abs.(X))
    X = (X.+H)./(2.0.*H)
    w = transpose(1:M)
    S = (sqrt.(2.0.*pi).*hyper).*exp.((-0.5.*hyper.^2).*((pi.*w./(2.0.*H)).^2))
    f = H.^(-0.5).*sin.(pi.*X.*w).*sqrt.(S)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I have never used Julia, but a a factor of 2 in speed between languages can be perfectly normal

Comment: What is the question? Please be specific and explicit, if you want to get a useful answer!

Comment: It would be nice, if you can provide actual timing and how you made them. It's a common thing at the beginning, to measure compile time, or benchmark global variables performance (which is notoriously slow)

Comment: Some broadcast are not actually needed, like the second row, the 2.0 .* H, most of the 5th row, etc... But I did try, you save only 4% by removing them.  Did you use`@btime features($X,$M,$hyper,$mid)` to benchmark? Otherwise you include compilation time or treat in the benchmarking the parameters as global variables. If you don't get answers here, try the [official discourse forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/). Questions like this one are answered very quickly!

Comment: In the last line, you create a matrix by broadcasting over a column vector (X) and a row vector (S). Is that what you want? It would be great if you could provide sample input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, your use of broadcasting isn't optimal. You are using it too much, and not enough ;)

Secondly, almost all the runtime (99.9%) is happening in the broadcasted `sin` expression, so the effort should be focused there.

And thirdly, you shouldn't really expect Julia to outperform Matlab in a case like this. This is exactly what Matlab has been optimized for: straightforward elementwise calls into optimized C/Fortran routines. Also, Matlab is multi-threaded by default, implicitly running the elementwise calls in parallel, while Julia requires you to be explicit about multi-threading.

For now, a factor of 2 difference doesn't seem unreasonable.

Still, let's make an effort. Here are a few comments first:

```
X = X .- mid
```

You are missing out on making the operation in-place, use

```
X .= X .- mid
```

instead. This saves an allocation of an intermediate array.

```
H = 4.0.*hyper.+maximum(abs.(X))
```

Broadcasting over scalars (`hyper`) is futile, and at worst, wasteful. And `abs.(X)` creates an unnecessary temporary array. Instead use the version of `maximum` with a function input, which is more efficient:

```
H = 4 * hyper + maximum(abs, X)
```

Here are some more unnecessary dots:

```
S = (sqrt.(2.0.*pi).*hyper).*exp.((-0.5.*hyper.^2).*((pi.*w./(2.0.*H)).^2))
```

Avoid broadcasting over scalars again and use integers most places instead of floats:

```
S = (sqrt(2pi) * hyper) .* exp.((-0.5 * hyper^2 * (pi/2H)^2) .* w.^2)
```

Note that `x^(-0.5)` is *much* slower than `1/sqrt(x)`, so

```
f = H.^(-0.5).*sin.(pi.*X.*w).*sqrt.(S)
```

should be

```
f = sin.(pi .* X .* w') .* (sqrt.(S)' ./ sqrt(H))
```

Let's put this together:

```
function features2(X::Vector{Float64},M::Int,hyper::Float64,mid::Float64)
    X .= X .- mid
    H = 4 * hyper + maximum(abs, X)
    X .= (X .+ H) ./ (2 * H)
    w = 1:M
    S = (sqrt(2pi) * hyper) .* exp.((-0.5 * hyper^2 * (pi/2H)^2) .* w.^2)
    f = sin.(pi .* X .* w') .* (sqrt.(S)' ./ sqrt(H))
    return f
end
```

Benchmarks:

```
jl> X = rand(10000);

jl> M = 100;

jl> hyper = rand();

jl> mid = 0.4;

jl> @btime features($X, $M, $hyper, $mid);
  17.339 ms (9 allocations: 7.86 MiB)

jl> @btime features2($X, $M, $hyper, $mid);
  17.173 ms (4 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

That's not much of a speedup. Fewer allocations, though. The problem is that runtime is dominated to an enormous degree by the `sin` broadcast.

Let's try multithreading. I have 8 cores, so I'm using 8 threads:

```
function features3(X::Vector{Float64},M::Int,hyper::Float64,mid::Float64)
    X .= X .- mid
    H = 4 * hyper + maximum(abs, X)
    X .= (X .+ H) ./ (2 * H)
    w = transpose(1:M)
    S = (sqrt(2pi) * hyper) .* exp.((-0.5 * hyper^2 * (pi/2H)^2) .* w.^2)
    f = similar(X, length(X), M)
    temp = sqrt.(S) ./ sqrt(H)
    Threads.@threads for j in axes(f, 2)
        wj = w[j]
        tempj = temp[j]
        for i in axes(f, 1)
            @inbounds f[i, j] = tempj * sin(pi * X[i] * w[j])
        end
    end
    return f
end
```

Bencmark:

```
jl> @btime features3($X, $M, $hyper, $mid);
  1.919 ms (45 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

That's a lot better, 9 times faster with a loop and explicit threading.

But there are still some options left: for example LoopVectorization.jl. You can install this amazing package, but you need a new version, there could be some installation issues, depending on what other packages you have. LoopVectorization has two macros of particular interest, `@avx` and `@avxt`, the former does a lot of work to vectorize (in a simd sense) your code, single-threaded, while latter does the same, but multi-threaded.

```
using LoopVectorization

function features4(X::Vector{Float64},M::Int,hyper::Float64,mid::Float64)
    X .= X .- mid
    H = 4 * hyper + maximum(abs, X)
    X .= (X .+ H) ./ (2 * H)
    w = collect(1:M)  # I have to use collect here due to some issue with LoopVectorization
    S = (sqrt(2pi) * hyper) .* exp.((-0.5 * hyper^2 * (pi/2H)^2) .* w.^2)
    f = @avx sin.(pi .* X .* w') .* (sqrt.(S)' ./ sqrt(H))
    return f
end

function features4t(X::Vector{Float64},M::Int,hyper::Float64,mid::Float64)
    X .= X .- mid
    H = 4 * hyper + maximum(abs, X)
    X .= (X .+ H) ./ (2 * H)
    w = collect(1:M)  # I have to use collect here due to some issue with LoopVectorization
    S = (sqrt(2pi) * hyper) .* exp.((-0.5 * hyper^2 * (pi/2H)^2) .* w.^2)
    f = @avxt sin.(pi .* X .* w') .* (sqrt.(S)' ./ sqrt(H))
    return f
end
```

The only difference between these functions is `@avx` vs `@avxt`.

Benchmarks:

```
jl> @btime features4($X, $M, $hyper, $mid);
  2.695 ms (5 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

A very nice speedup for the single threaded case.

```
jl> @btime features4t($X, $M, $hyper, $mid);
  431.700 μs (5 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

The multi-threaded avx code is 40x as fast as the original code on my laptop. Not bad?

Comment: Also worth mentioning `sinpi`

Comment: My understanding is that `sinpi` is more accurate, but slower. I see a 70% slowdown when replacing `sin(pi*..)` with `sinpi(..)`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! One question though: when multiplying by scalar constants why is it better to keep them Integers instead of floats (append .0)? If I run simple tests having them as ints perform worse than having them as floats

Comment: The performance should be the same, so I suspect that there is something wrong with the benchmark in that case. The reason for using integers is two-fold: it's more readable and brief. And it does not inadvertently change the types (as much). For example `2*x` is an integer if x is an integer, a single precision float if `x`, and so on. While `2.0*x` turns the result into a double precision float in those cases. Integers are less disruptive.

Comment: @DNF Currently `sinpi` is slower, but it should be as fast since it has a much simpler reduction. Currently it uses `sin_kernel` and `cos_kernel` to save code, but if it had it's own kernels, than I'm pretty sure it would be faster. I'll hopefully have a PR that fixes this soon.